# The first head/chief/leader/etc of the Federal Housing Administration?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century

Did the FHA have a head? If it did who was he/she?

Comment: This is trivia, but it's not easy to find, so I think it's on-topic.

Comment: I expected that it would be trivial to find; I was wrong.

Comment: [James A Moffett](http://www.scribd.com/doc/23806997/The-FHA-s-First-25-Years).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[James Moffett](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=15015) according to this letter from FDR.
(sorry for my earlier erroneous answer).